# Converting a mountain bike to a urban commuter

Tags: mountain-bike, commuter, urban-riding

While cleaning up our storage room I saw my dad's old bike collecting dust on a corner (he used to bike a lot before) so I asked him if I can have it and he said yes.

[image: actual bike]

So for my question can I transform this bike into a commuter or am I better-off selling it and buying a new commuter bike? Though I really like to keep this one for some sentimental reasons rather than to sell it.

My budget is also limited, still finishing my college degree. I'll be using this going to my university and back, though I live in the city our roads/bicycle lanes here in Manila, Philippines are terrible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. The good news is that I think your question has already been answered. For example, in the question I link to in my other comment. But also, I think you'll find there are other questions along these lines - look at the links to the right, or use the search box in the top right corner. These should give you a good idea of the most important things to look for when riding your bike on the mean streets of Manilla!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feelings are definitely very important, but a dual suspension bike with a two-crown fork is a difficult start for a commuter bike. Especially if your budget is limited.

I would think that you should inflate the tires well and take a ride to school to see what it's like in its current condition. If you can block suspension, that might help.  I guess if you love or hate your first ride, it'd be a part of an answer to your question.

If it's neither a bliss nor a hell of a ride, you could ask a more specific question, e.g., for advice on particular problems you experience. A possible way out is to sell certain components (such as the fork) and buy new ones that would fit your purpose better.

But yeah, after all, it's a beautiful machine, personally I'd try hard to keep it. Good luck!